# Inverse Binomial Expected value

Tags: binomial-distribution

Let's $x$ be a random variable with a binomial distribution ($x \sim B(n,p)$). I know that the expected value of a binomial is $E(x) = n \cdot p $ but the inverse of a binomial?

- $E\big(\frac{1}{x}\big)$ = ???

#### EDIT

$Y \sim unknown$ and $X \sim B(n,p)$

$E\big(\frac{Y}{X}\big) = E(Y) \cdot E\big(\frac{1}{X}\big)$

Comment: I wonder whether such general result exists!

Comment: What is $1/x$ when $x=0$?

Comment: @pushpen.paul I don't know if such a general result exist but since i need to compute the expected value of a ratio between two random variables I found this problem.

Comment: @StefanHansen I compute those values via simulation, so $0 \ge X \ge n$. If there is some cases where $x=0$ then those cases are $=\inf$

Comment: In that case, the expectation is obviously infinite, since there is positive probability that $x=0$.

Comment: It takes only a *single* infinite case to make the expectation infinite!

Answer (score 2):

Since $\Pr[X = 0] = p^n > 0$, what is $${\rm E}\left[\frac{1}{X}\right] = \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{i} \Pr\left[X = i\right] = ?$$

Comment: Check your expression carefully. Should $i$ start from $0$? Doesn't it make the whole expression meaningless?