# If missing data process is known and it is MNAR, is it possible to get an unbiased estimate of parameter?

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, panel-data, missing-data, unbiased-estimator

I was reading on missing data handling techniques from "Statistical Analysis with
Missing Data Second Edition" by Little and Rubin. In example 6.22 they consider that $y_1, y_2, ... y_n$ are i.i.d. exponential random variables. i.e. $f(y_i) = \theta^{-1}e^{-\dfrac y \theta}$. Further $y_i$ is only recorded if it is less than a cutoff $c$. Suppose $r$ out of $n$ observations are recorded and rest are missing. A corresponding missingness indicator $M_i$ is 0 if it is missing and 1 if observed. They show that the estimate based on the joint likelihood of missing data process and observed data gives

$\hat{\theta} = \dfrac {\Sigma_{i=1}^{r} y_i + (n-r)c} r $

My question is if this estimate is unbiased?

**Here is what I've tried so far:**

Since the observed $y_i$ belong to a truncated exponential distribution with support $[0, c)$, $E(y_i) = \dfrac \theta {1-e^{-\dfrac c \theta}} (1-e^{-\dfrac c \theta}(1+\dfrac c \theta))$.

$\Rightarrow E(\hat{\theta}) = \dfrac \theta {1-e^{-\dfrac c \theta}} (1-e^{-\dfrac c \theta}(1+\dfrac c \theta)) + nc * E(\dfrac {1} {r}) - c$

Since $r$, the number of observed data which are less than $c$ follows a binomial distribution with probability of success $p(y < c)$, $\dfrac {1} {r}$ is the inverse of binomial distribution. I tried to calculate this expected value but I ended up concluding that it is infinity. So it seems to me that the bias also infinity?

*Link: [Inverse Binomial Expected value](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105034/inverse-binomial-expected-value)*

**Simulations that I performed to check unbiasedness of estimator**

I also performed some simualations to get a rough idea about how biased the estimator is, and from the simulations it seems to me it may be unbiased and its variance in inversely proportional to the cutoff $c$. However I can't conclude from simulations. Nevertheless here is my R code:

```
library(ggplot2)

numObs = 100
len = 100
cutoff = 30
origEstimator = vector("numeric", len)
newEstimator = vector("numeric", len)
for(i in 1:len){
  sample = rexp(n = numObs, rate = 0.05)
  origEstimator[i] = mean(sample)

  truncSample = sample[sample<cutoff]
  r = length(truncSample)
  newEstimator[i] = (sum(truncSample) + (numObs-r)*cutoff)/r
}

ggplot(data = data.frame(mean=c(origEstimator, newEstimator), type=c(rep("Complete data", len), rep("Adjusted", len)))) + 
  geom_density(aes(x=mean, color=type))
```

**Screenshot from the book**:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting question.

First I will show that $r>0$. If $r=0$, then there is no observed data, and the likelihood function is no longer concave, thus this statistical problem is not well defined. Given $r>0$, $E(1/r)$ should be finite.

Let $p=\mathrm{Pr}(y_i<c) = 1-\mathrm{exp}(-c/\theta)$. We have $$E(1/r) = \sum_{r=1}^n \binom{n}{r} p^r (1-p)^{n-r}/r = n p (1-p)^{n-1} F(1, 1, 1-n;2, 2;p/(p-1)),$$
where $F(\cdot)$ is the [generalized hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function). $E(\hat{\theta})$ can be computed by plugging $E(1/r)$ into the equation in the question.

The following numerical computation shows that $E(\hat{\theta}) = \theta$, i.e., $\hat\theta$ that considers the MNAR (missing not at random) mechanism is unbiased. Note that `genhypergeo()` used to calculate the generalized hypergeometric function has numerical error, but the above summation can be computed exactly.

```
library(hypergeo)

theta_hat = function(theta, n = 100) {
  c = .5*theta # arbitrary c can be used
  p = 1 - exp(-c/theta)
  theta*(1-exp(-c/theta)*(c/theta+1))/(1-exp(-c/theta)) + (n *c) *
    (genhypergeo(U=c(1,1,1-n), L=c(2,2), z=p/(p-1)) * n * p * (1-p)^(n-1)) - c
}

theta = 1:10
plot(theta, sapply(theta, theta_hat), ylab='theta_hat')
abline(a=0, b=1)
```

[image]